# Hooking in to replace the Sidebar/Widget areas

Tags: plugins, themes, widgets, hooks

The Goal: To replace the sidebar on all sites across my network with content loaded from a plugin, *across all themes.*

I need a way of over-riding the sidebar/main widget area on all sites across my network.

I have written a plugin which generates the sidebar with a function call, but **how can I get this content to completely replace the sidebar?** At present I can only call a hook as `get_sidebar()` happens, not replace that action.

```
add_action('get_sidebar', 'my_get_sidebar', 11);
```

Additionally, this makes my sidebar appear on all sidebars on the page, I only want it to overwrite the main one (sidebar-one?) and have the others left blank.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into having your sidebars utilize the remove action function.

Then you can remove a sidebar and replace it in a function any number of ways.

For instance (this examples using a conditional based on a page called **some-page**.

```
function change_sidebar_yay() {
    if ( is_single('some-page') ) {
        remove_action( 'old_sidebar', 'your_function' ); //this is sidebar you want removed
        add_action('get_sidebar', 'my_get_sidebar', 11);
    }
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

The `old_sidebar` and `your_function` is the name and the function name of the sidebar you want removed, you will have to look in your theme to find the actual values the theme author used ( usually in **functions.php** but not always).

Also if the theme is hardcoded or does not create sidebars using hooks/actions this will not work.

Comment: Could you define what 'old_sidebar' and 'your_function' should be? I essentially want to stop get_sidebar()

Comment: Updated the answer to be more clear

Comment: I need this to work across all themes, meaning I can't pick and choose from a theme file, is it impossible in this case?

Comment: It's not impossible but you will have to create a network wide plugin, so it will effect all network themes even if they are different.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, for i to happen network-wide, but all themes have different names for widgets so it will be impossible?

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but perhaps can the plugin [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) be a good starting point to develop your function from?